# Meaning of "Dare I say there really is a god after all"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of sentence, I am confused.

> Dare I say there really is a god after all

I am guessing that it is saying: *I have dare to say that God is there* (not getting meaning of phrase 'after all'). Am I correct?

I got sentence from here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83761/android-7-0-system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so  Just press ctrl+f & search by word 'Dare', you will find it.

Thank you

Comment: Those are expressions. Follow these links. **dare I say/suggest**: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dare-i-say-suggest **after all**: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/after-all

Comment: We always appreciate when you tell us where the sentence came from. [Here’s why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: Thanks your comments. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83761/android-7-0-system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so from here I got that sentence. Just press ctrl+f & search by word 'Dare', you will find it.

Comment: @Michael Rybkin only one line available there it would be nice if you answer my question with few example.

Comment: @Arvindraja The links I posted have all you need: definitions along with a bunch of examples.

Comment: @Michael Rybkin Yeah got it. :)

Comment: @Arvindraja That quote that you've got says something along these lines: **I was an atheist my entire life and always denied the existence of God, but despite all this, it seems like God does really exist. (because of this miraculous event that happened)**

Comment: Notice that in your context it's just an expression used to show happiness. Stuart is not stating his beliefs, he's showing that he's really pleased because he has averted some problems with his app.

Comment: @RubioRic-Even Stuart showing his happiness, indirectly he is expressing that he believe in God & it is well relating with Michael Rybkin example. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with you. You can use expressions like "oh, my God!", "for Christ sake" or the one you have pointed out without actually believing in God.

Comment: I think that Michael Rybkin has nailed the explanation of the phrase but without taking into account the context

Comment: I respect your word. I might be wrong due to lack of English knowledge. It to be explored more by me. So we can use this phrase in context what Stuart did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase **after all** refers to some experience or event after which one's attitude, opinion, or belief is opposite the one rather firmly held before the experience. It is a way of saying that the earlier notion has proven wrong.

Let's say that I'm looking for my car keys and my wife suggests that I look for them in the car. "You may have forgotten to take them out" she says. I reply "I know they are not out in the car. I distinctly remember placing them here on the counter." But then I do go outdoors and look in the car, and the keys are there. Then I could say "The keys were in the car after all."

Comment: Thank you for your example. It is very clear. Could you please shad some light on 'Dare I say...'

Comment: @Arvindraja: *Dare I say* could be paraphrased "Do I take a risk and state, without any sort of hedging or qualification, that ..."

Comment: oh nice. you explained more in less words.

Answer (score 3):

> Dare I say there really is a god after all?

I think that @Michael Rybkin has nailed it. Let me quote him

> I was an atheist my entire life and always denied the existence of
>   God, but despite all this, it seems like God does really exist.
>   (because of this miraculous event that happened)

**After all** means

> After all I've said against the existence of God until this moment,
>   this miracoulous situation has proven me wrong.

But also I want you to notice that Stuart, the member of the linked forum, is just expressing happiness because he has "averted a disaster and his application works on all devices". He may be still an atheist. You can use expressions like that or like "oh, my God" or "for Christ sake" without actually believing in any god.

Comment: @Arvindraja You're welcome. Glad to help :-)